# Remove Temporary Tables from Apache SQL Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have `registertemptable` in `Apache Spark` using `Zeppelin` below:

```
val hvacText = sc.textFile("...")

case class Hvac(date: String, time: String, targettemp: Integer, actualtemp: Integer, buildingID: String)

val hvac = hvacText.map(s => s.split(",")).filter(s => s(0) != "Date").map(
    s => Hvac(s(0), 
            s(1),
            s(2).toInt,
            s(3).toInt,
            s(6))).toDF()

hvac.registerTempTable("hvac")
```

After I have done with my queries with this temp table, how do I remove it ?

I checked all docs and it seems I am getting nowhere.

Any guidance ?

Answer (score 55):

**Spark 2.x**

For temporary views you can use [`Catalog.dropTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog@dropTempView%28viewName:String%29:Boolean):

```
spark.catalog.dropTempView("df")
```

For global views you can use [`Catalog.dropGlobalTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog@dropGlobalTempView%28viewName:String%29:Boolean):

```
spark.catalog.dropGlobalTempView("df")
```

Both methods are safe to call if view doesn't exist and, since Spark 2.1, return boolean indicating if the operation succeed.

**Spark 1.x**

You can use [`SQLContext.dropTempTable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext):

```
scala.util.Try(sqlContext.dropTempTable("df"))
```

It can be still used in Spark 2.0, but delegates processing to `Catalog.dropTempView` and is safe to use if table doesn't exist.

Comment: does spark.stop() will remove this temporary tables.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to remove your temp table on zeppelin, try like this.

```
sqlc.dropTempTable("hvac")
```

or

```
%sql DROP VIEW hvac
```

And you can get the informations you need from spark API Docs(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package)

Comment: sqlc.dropTempTable("hvac") works. The latter doesnt. Thank you very much !

Comment: References for `DROP VIEW`/`DROP TABLE` with `%sql`: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/drop-table.html

Answer (score 12):

in new ver (2.0 and latest) of spark. 
one should use: `createOrReplaceTempView` in place of `registerTempTable` (depricated)
and corresponding method to deallocate is: `dropTempView`

```
spark.catalog.dropTempView("temp_view_name") //drops the table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql drop table/view statement to remove it like below

```
spark.sql("drop view hvac");
```